# Spanish reading passages with a focus on specific grammar

Tags: grammar, reading, spanish

Is there such a thing as reading passages where the passage has been specifically created with a focus on a specific part of grammar? If so, what are they called, and where can I find them?

I'm currently using readers for Spanish (such as "Read and Think Spanish" and "Stories from Spain / Historias de España"), but they don't allow me to intensively practice a particular piece of grammar, and they may contain grammar that I haven't learnt yet, which usually leads to me not attempting to understand all the grammar in the passage.

Comment: In my experience with English graded readers, they usually use grammar appropriate for a student at the given level of profficiency - a book marked as using only 300 most common words will use a much simpler grammar than a book based on 1500 words. In other words, if you find the grammar in your chosen readers too difficult, maybe you should pick up a lower level of difficulty anyway. That said, it is expected that you use readers to practice reading comprehension, i.e., you should not try to understand every single word or every single grammatical structure.